# Linux can't delete files

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find

I have a problem with removing files when I find them.
Task : must find files with spaces and remove them

my try :)

```
rm $(find -L /root | grep -i ' ')
```

But i have errors:

```
rm: cannot remove `/root/test': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `2.txt': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `/root/test': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `3.txt': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `/root/test': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `1.txt': No such file or directory
```

Please help resolve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not thus:

```
find /root -type f -name '* *' -exec rm -f {} ';'
```

Comment: Would be good if you actually explained to the OP why their command doesn't work, and how `find -exec` is better, and why.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you are finding files with spaces in, or quotes. Try this:

```
find /test/path -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

What this will do is send the filenames to stdout separate by `NULL` bytes, which `xargs` will take as delimiters. This allow spaces, quotes and other such fun in the output.

Now, if you are removing directories, `rm` is not going to work. So you might want to add a `-type f` to the above.

Note that gnu `find` itself has a `-delete` operator which will delete files for you, but you wanted to know why. Hence a shorter route would be:

```
find /test/path -delete
```

This will deal with directories too if you do not add `-type f`. It will also handle deleting the deepest things first (think about why this is needed).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an -exec argument to the find command to run a command with the resulting file as an argument. In your case, the following command will do what you want.

`-type f` will print only files. If you want only directories then use `-type d`. If you use neither of these then it will print both files and directories.

As this is a delete operation, first run the command and see if it's printing the files you want.

```
find /root -type f -name '* *'
```

Then if everything is okay, run this to delete them.

```
find /root -type f -name '* *' -exec rm {} \;
```